# Second Chance Page Replacement

Tags: c, page-tables

Why is my function for second chance page replacement pager system not working?

The function only selects the victim frame and returns it.

If there is a free frame, it returns it. Otherwise it has to select a frame that is currently in use based on the SC (second chance) algorithm.

It returns the frame number of the selected frame but does not
update any pager data.

My function is:

```
// select the frame based on second chance, passing the page
uint64 sc_select_victim_frame(pager_data* pager)
{   
    // these first 4 lines its like fifo, if frame for this page is not occopied (free)
    //then just return it,
    then am just incrementing the sc_count for future indexing of fifo,

    if(!(pager->frames[0].occupied)){
        return pager->SC_count;
    }

    pager->SC_count +=1;
    pager->SC_count = pager->SC_count % pager->num_frames;


    for(uint64 i=0; i<pager->num_frames; i++){
        if(pager->frames[i].occupied){
            if(!pager->second_chance[i]){
                pager->second_chance[i] = 1;
            }
            return i;
        }
    }



    return pager->SC_count;

}
```

The pager struct has:

```
typedef struct _pager_data{

uint64 num_pages, num_frames, page_sz, num_procs;
frame* frames;
page_table_entry** page_tables;
uint64 SC_count;
bool* second_chance; // I have created this array to track the second chance

} pager_data;
```

Page table entry struct is:

```
typedef struct _page_table_entry{
    uint64 flags : 12; 
    uint64 frame : 40; 
    uint64 unused : 12; 
} page_table_entry;
```

Finally, my frame is:

```
typedef struct _frame{
    bool occupied; 
    uint64 pid, page_number;
} frame;
```

I have added `bool* second_chance;` inside pager but I'm not sure if that's right. Is my second chance algorithm not correct?

Why is my function not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

My solution at the end is;

```
uint64 sc_select_victim_frame(pager_data* pager)
{   

    if(!(pager->frames[0].occupied)){
        pager->SC_count +=1;
        pager->SC_count = pager->SC_count % pager->num_frames;
        return pager->SC_count;
    }



    if(pager->second_chance[pager->SC_count] == 0){
        pager->second_chance[pager->SC_count] = 1;
        pager->SC_count +=1;
        pager->SC_count = pager->SC_count % pager->num_frames;
        return pager->SC_count;
    }

    pager->second_chance[pager->SC_count] = 0;
    return pager->SC_count;



}
```